# How to load data without changing the scrolling position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the scroll position change when I prepend data in given data. I scroll to top it prepend data but scroll position goes to top. But I saw lot of example in Facebook and whatsapp in which when it load previous data scroll position remain same.

Can we retain the scroll position ? http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/17/

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() === 0 && pages.length) {
        console.log("up");
        $("#next").html('')
        $("#pre").html('')
        $("#next").html($("#current").html());
        $("#current").html('');


           $("#current").html(pages.pop())
            .prependTo($("#fullContainer"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be done in Javascript:

One way to do this is to use a hidden div of the same height and width as the one you are prepending and measure it's scrollHeight when you add the content to it. Then, after you prepend the text, simply set the content div's scrollTop to the scrollHeight of the hidden div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        $("div#hiddenDiv").html("Testing<br><br><br>");

        var coffset = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").scrollHeight;

        $("div#content").prepend($("div#hiddenDiv").html());
        document.getElementById("content").scrollTop += coffset;

    }, 5000);

});
```

In the following fiddle, text will be prepended to the div after a few seconds, but the scroll 
position will not change.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ5q9/2/)

Comment: But it not a got answer because first it goes to top and then scroll down

Comment: I must not be understanding your problem. What do you mean it goes to the top and then scrolls down?

Comment: @user2484319 The simple truth of the matter is that when you prepend text to your window, no matter what it is, you will scroll back to the top. That is what the prepend function does.

Comment: I will explain..example when you use app like Facebook or watapp .when you see message and go to top while scrolling it load the previous message without changing the scroll position

Comment: yes I know prepend default functionality  so that why I am asking how those Facebook developer did

Comment: Yes, exactly. Check my revision; I left out a simple `+=`, rather than an `=`. http://jsfiddle.net/TZ5q9/2/

Comment: Ok ..I will change in my fiddle the then i will tell you .can we do same when scroll to bottom ?

Comment: The code will work no matter where you are on the page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/20/ You have to have a hidden div to get the height from.

Comment: internally first it goes to top then again it reset the scroll position ? may I right ?

Comment: Yes. Here's the order: You set the html of a hidden div of the same height and width of your container to be your prepended text. You then get the height of the content in that hidden div. Next prepend the text onto the container (which changes the scroll position). Finally, add the change in scroll position you got from the hidden div to the scrollTop of the container (which moves the scroll position back to where it was).

Comment: yes it is working fine  …but can we do same thing when user scroll to bottom ?

Comment: there is no other way to do same task ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Give me a minute to think of how to tell when you are at the bottom.

Comment: I think you again not understand the question.i just check if user user scroll to bottom and append data scroll position remain same..

Comment: As same as we did in scrolling top

Comment: Oh, well if you want to append data, you don't have to change the scroll position at all. Just append it when it gets to the bottom. http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/23/